# How do I prove that this system has a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $V=(\mathbb R^N,(\cdot,\cdot))$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the standard Euclidean inner product. Let $A$ be a $N \times N$ positive definite matrix. 
Let $B$ be a $M \times N$ matrix, with $M \le N-1$ with $\text{rank }B=M$.

Show that the following linear system has one and only one solution $(u,\lambda)\in \mathbb R^N \times \mathbb R^M$
$$
\begin{cases}
Au +B^T \lambda &=c,\\
Bu&=d.
\end{cases}
$$

Thanks in advance!

I found this useful formula in the book by Bernstein: Matrix Mathematics, Princeton Univeristy Press, 2005. I applied it to the studied problem and the outcome is the following ($\mathbb O$ denotes the zero matrix)

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A&B^T\\
B&\mathbb O
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\\
\quad=
\begin{pmatrix}
A^{-1}+A^{-1} B^T(\mathbb O- BA^{-1}B^T)^{-1}BA^{-1} & -A^{-1}B^T(\mathbb O-BA^{-1}B^T)^{-1} \\ -(\mathbb O-BA^{-1}B^T)^{-1}BA^{-1} & (\mathbb O-BA^{-1}B^T)^{-1} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

but I need to show that $B A^{-1}B^T$ is invertible and I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Well $B^T$ has rank $M$ so you have a left inverse $C$ such that $CB=I_M$.

Similarly $B$ has a right inverse $C'$ such that $BC'=I_M$.

So $C'AC$ is a suitable inverse for $BA^{-1}B^T$.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. shouldn't it be $[C']^T A C$ the inverse matrix?